# jQuery Rotate with slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that when you click on it opens up the the content within, at the top of the bar I have an arrow image that if the content is closed (default position) the arrow is pointing to the right and when the content is open I want the arrow image to rotate to pointing down.

I am using jQueryRotate to rotate the image and I have all the elements working, but what I can't get it to work when toggling, I can only get the image to rotate once when opening the content, I have where I have got to here

```
$("#ProductHeaderWrap1").click(function () {
    $("#ProductDetailsToggle1").stop().slideToggle("slow");
});


$("#ProductHeaderWrap1").click(function () {
    $("#ProductHeaderWrap1").find(".arrow").rotate({
        animateTo: 90
    }, {
        duration: 500
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cgF4a/ along with some worked on jQuery attempts, I just need the image to rotate to 0 when clicked to close the div.

Thanks for any help,
J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to do this with CSS, take a look:

```
img.open {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear; 
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s linear;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 1s linear;
          transition: transform 1s linear;
}
img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s linear;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 1s linear;
          transition: transform 1s linear;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ProductHeaderWrap1").click(function () {
        $("#ProductDetailsToggle1").stop().slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).find("#Image1").toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

## [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgF4a/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the input but that doesn't 'animate' the image into position as it currently does.

Comment: All you need to do is add some transitions to the CSS, updated my answer.

Comment: thanks that works fine, although would still like to know if possible in jQuery, will accept answer if I find out it's not possible in jQuery.

Comment: It is possible, but this is the recommended way of animating an element on click. jQuery animations are not always the smoothest and can be quite a bit slower than CSS animations(especially on mobile devices). If you wanted to do it with jQuery you would have to throw in an `if statement` that says if `#ProductDetailsToggle1` is visible, rotate to 0 else rotate to 90(or vice versa).